# How to properly set values to the controls of an instantiated View Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class ErrorMessageViewController:

```
// ErrorMessageViewController.h
@interface ErrorMessageViewController: UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel* messageTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel* messageContent;
@end

// ErrorMessageViewController.m
@implementation ErrorMessage
@synthesize messageTitle, messageContent;
@end
```

And I instantiate this view controller like this:

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ErrorMessageViewController * errorMessage = (ErrorMessageViewController *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ErrorMessage"];
[[errorMessage messageTitle] setText:@"Error"];
[[errorMessage messageContent] setText:@"Duplicate ID"];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:errorMessage animated:YES];
```

But the appearing View Controller's messageTitle and messageContent UILabel is empty. I have double check and make sure that the `UILabel`s are connected to the Storyboard's `UILabel`s.

Why is this happened? How to properly init an object's controls from `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// ErrorMessageViewController.h
@interface ErrorMessageViewController: UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel* messageTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel* messageContent;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *msg;

@end


UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ErrorMessageViewController * errorMessage = (ErrorMessageViewController *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ErrorMessage"];
errorMessage.title = @"Error";
errorMessage.msg = @"Duplicate ID";

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:errorMessage animated:YES];
```

In your 'viewDidLoad'

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    messageTitle.text = title;
    messageContent.text = msg;
}
```

Comment: Hey, this works! Thanks! Can I ask why this works, instead of setting the values directly to the controls?

Comment: Because upon your initialization it is not yet created. Your outlet are still null whether you set it to strong. Its like the viewController's View isn't yet created so upon viewDidLoad it works since on this part loadView() is already called and your outlets are created.

Comment: Agree, and change the outlets to weak.

Comment: @nferocious76 okay. thanks! Can I ask one more thing? Before, I also make a function to init the `title` and `msg` like `initWithTitle:andContent:`, which I call before `pushViewController:animated:` to replace `errorMessage.text = @"Error"` and `errorMessage.msg = @"Duplicate ID"`. But when viewDidLoad is called, their content is different (apparently, they return to become an uninitialised string, or even unallocated string, because the debugger raised error when I tried to access these variables when I init them using function like that). Why is that happened?

Comment: Because even if you pass it like that.. not until your view controller is pushed your view is just then prepared for you. What you can do is to fully customize it and start with loadView()

Comment: Note to your custom init: If you do it like that the content you'll see is the content set in the IB.